# Forge Viewer: Efficiently add multiple instances of the same geometry

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a viewer application that loads multiple (many) documents into a scene. The same components are repeated many times. I am calling ViewingApplication.loadDocument(...) once per file, and Viewer3D.loadModel(...) once per instance in order to set the placementTransform.

However Viewer3D.loadModel(...) appears to be downloading the geometry each call, despite the URL not changing. Is there a more efficient way to add the same geometry multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `viewer.loadModel` is the only way to load an extra model in the scene at the moment, however the viewer is caching resources when loading a model so the cost of loading the same model should be negligible.